# Cannot Access wp-admin as redirects to wp-signup.php?

Tags: wp-admin

when i go to www.resourceful.ninja/wp-admin i get sent to http://resourceful.ninja/wp-signup.php?new=resourceful.darrencleary.com.

This happened after multisite install.

Can anyone help in fixing this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add the define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', '' ); in wp-config.php right below the multisite rules!

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?